# PERL: unpacking huge data results in unusually long processing time

Tags: perl, unpack

I am trying to separate out header and pixel data from a bitmap file. Using following code

```
($bmpHdr1, @bmpData1[0..$bmpSize-1]) = unpack "(H$hdrNibbleLen)(H2)*", $data1;
```

Works like a charm on small files, but results in ridiculous extended processing time when used on a larger file. For example, a 16MB bitmap image, in fact I have never waited long enough for it to complete.

```
($bmpHdr1, @bmpData1) = unpack "(H$hdrNibbleLen)(H*)", $data1;
```

works well but I get all the pixel data in the first element of the list, needs additional regex ops to get the data in the desired format. Is there a way to do this with just `unpack`?

Expected output: upack pixel data with byte level granularity and store each byte in different list element.

Real expectation:

I wish to compare two bitmaps and find the X,Y of the mismatching pixel and corresponding data. Because of padding and different bits-per-pixel (some are 24bpp) finding the mismatching pixel becomes a nightmare if not separated at byte level. Well at least the way I am doing it.

```
my $errPixY = floor($errByte/$rowSize);
my $errPixX = ($errByte - ($errPixY * $rowSize))/($header1{DibHdrBpp}/8);
```

Comment: What are you hoping to do with the data after extraction?

Comment: Why do you need each byte as a separate list element? That's awfully wasteful of space and processing time.

Comment: I wish to compare two bitmaps and find the X,Y of the mismatching pixel and corresponding data. Becuase of padding and different bit-per-pixel find it become a nightmare if not separated at byte level.

Comment: Pixel or pixels? Do you mean only one pixel is different?

Comment: for now just the first mismatching pixel in its chronological order.

Comment: I wish to compare two bitmaps and find the X,Y of the mismatching pixel and corresponding data. Becuase of padding and different bit-per-pixel (some are 24bpp) finding the mismatching pixel becomes a nightmare if not separated at byte level. Well atleast the way am doing it. 
    **my $errPixY = floor($errByte/$rowSize);
    my $errPixX = ($errByte - ($errPixY * $rowSize))/($header1{DibHdrBpp}/8);**

Comment: You can't use the https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::BMP module?

Comment: wanted to make it available for extended audience, without use of modules.. Just basic perl install. Not many in our group are pro-perl yet.

Comment: If you're not "pro-perl", that's all the more reason to use existing code.

Answer (score 3):

XOR:

```
0 0 -> 0
0 1 -> 1
1 0 -> 1
1 1 -> 0
```

Leave the payload in string form and XOR the two strings:

```
my $xor = $bmp_data1 ^ $bmp_data2;
while ($xor =~ /[^\0]/g) {
   my $pos = $-[0];
   printf "Difference at byte %d (%02X vs %02X)\n",
      $pos,
      ord(substr($bmp_data1, $pos, 1)),
      ord(substr($bmp_data2, $pos, 1));
}
```

---

A start at finding out to which pixel a byte belongs.

```
sub to_num { unpack('N', substr(("\0"x4).$_[0], -4)) }

my $Bpp = $bpp<8 ? 1 : $bpp/8;
die "Unsupported number of bits per pixel\n" if $Bpp != int($Bpp);
die "Unsupported number of bits per pixel\n" if $Bpp > 4;

my $xor = $data1 ^ $data2;
while ($xor =~ /[^\0]/g) {
   my $pos = $-[0] - ($-[0] % $Bpp);
   pos($xor) = $pos + $Bpp;

   if ($bpp >= 8) {
      my $pixel = $pos / $Bpp
      my $x = $pixel % $row_size;
      my $y = ($pixel - $x) / $row_size;
      my $val1 = to_num(substr($data1, $pos, $Bpp));
      my $val2 = to_num(substr($data2, $pos, $Bpp));
      ...
   } else {
      my $sub_data1 = substr($data1, $pos, 1);
      my $sub_data2 = substr($data2, $pos, 1);
      ... split into pixels and compare those ...
   }
}
```